# "Expérience gedanken" for "expérience de pensée"

Tags: usage, néologismes, science, académique

In the English written scientific literature it is common practice to use **gedanken experiment** instead of the English translation **thought experiment**. See [here](https://scholar.google.gr/scholar?hl=el&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=gedanken%20experiments%20poroelasticity&btnG=). In French (university level and higher) peut-on employer **expérience gedanken** au lieu de **expérience de pensée** ? E.g.

> Because of this limiting upper bound for the stress, it is to be kept in mind that all plasticity experiments (including gedanken experiments) are done with displacement control.
>
> En raison de cette limite supérieure limitant pour la contrainte, il convient de garder à l'esprit que toutes les expériences de plasticité (y compris les expériences gedanken) sont effectuées avec un contrôle de déplacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Réponse limitée à mon expérience personnelle :

- Je n'ai jamais lu le terme d' *expérience de pensée* utilisé dans un document scientifique par l'auteur des travaux objets de sa publication.
- Je ne l'ai rencontré que dans les publications d'auteurs français analysant ou relatant les travaux d'autres personnes.
- Dans ce contexte, lorsque les autres personnes ont publié leurs travaux en allemand (ce qui est de plus en plus rare) le terme de *gedanken experiment* était effectivement utilisé mais soit entre parenthèses soit, comme il se doit en bonne typographie pour une formule étrangère, entre guillemets.

Alors... *"common practice, common practice..."* Hmmm... Je me permets de croire qu'il en est de même pour les anglo-saxons, [la dernière expérience de pensée en date](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11490.pdf) ne m'apparaissant pas contredire mes propos... ;-)

<sub>Note que *gedanken* ou pas... ça manque un peu de pêche on dirait mais c'est hyper cool ce truc de "*solar radiation pressure*" tu trouves pas ? ;-)</sub>